# Set image to full screen height on PhoneGap - Understanding window.devicePixelRatio

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution, viewport-units, html5-fullscreen, pixel-density

I'm trying to set an image to be the full height of a screen on a phoneGap app. Currently, I'm using the following code to determine the screen "dimensions" and I'm using javascript to set the image resolution to those dims.

```
$('.fullPageImage').height(window.screen.availHeight);
```

This produces the desired result on the iPhone 6 (retina display) as well as rendering on my laptop. The problem is when I try it on my Galaxy Note-3, the image is HUGE, and here's why: When I `console.log(window.screen.availHeight);` the Note seems to think its height is **1920** pixels - whereas my iPhone 6 only has **647** (and it's a retina display), so I know 1920 is not the actual number of pixels (or is it?). I looked into how the device is obtaining its `window.screen.availHeight` and found out there's this variable called `window.devicePixelRatio` and its value on the Note 3 is **3**. I figured the viewport dimension on the Note 3 is 360x640, so the **3** for devicePixelRatio makes sense. Now, what puzzles me is that when I `console.log(window.devicePixelRatio);` on my iPhone 6, the result is **2**. I tried setting the image height to 1/3 of the "availHeight" value using this code:

```
$('.fullPageImage').height(window.screen.availHeight/window.devicePixelRatio);
```

and it works great on the Note 3 (since it shrinks the image height down to 360 - as it should be), but on the iPhone, shrinking the image down to 324 (or something close) means the image onlly appears over half the page height.

My question is, instead of dividing by the devicePixelRatio, is there another variable I can obtain from the device in order to determine the ratio by which to shrink the image? The resulting ratio should **1** on the iPhone and **1/3** on the Note 3 in order for the image to correctly appear over the full height.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: cant you just use `$(window).height()`?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that existed. I tried it, and found a few other possible solutions, but unfortunately `$(document).height()` and `$(window).height()` both return **320** on the Note 3. Lastly, `screen.height` returns 1920... 

This device is starting to annoy me haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than explicitly setting the height, you should have the capability to use viewport units with CSS... so you could do something like the following:

```
$('.fullPageImage').css("height", "100vh");
```

That would set the height to 100% vertical height of the viewport, whatever that value might be.

You might also want to look into adding a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag to your header.

Comment: Thank you! It might work, except the reason I need to work with the integer value is because I want to subtract 90px for my footer. In other words, if I could do something like:
`$('.fullPageImage').css("height", "100vh - 90px");`
that would be perfect! Any thoughts?

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion, and estimated that the footer would take up about 6% of the screen height, so using:
`$('.fullPageImage').css("height", "94vh");` ended upworking really well for my purpose, but nonetheless, there should be a way to obtain the "CSS" screen resolution. On the iPhone, all of the methods mentioned above return the CSS screen height (667 or 647 - due to the status bar), but the Android keeps returning the "True" resolution. (These are the terms I found correspond to those values as tabulated here:
http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels/)

Comment: @JonHaider Note that `vh` might not work for all of your desired targets: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: You can always use `calc(100vh - 90px)`